# Does <pages validateRequest="false" /> in Web.config still matter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

ASP.NET MVC application, target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Pretty old project with a bunch of legacy code.

Web.config file in Views folder contains the following part:

```
<system.web>

    <!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
    -->

    <pages validateRequest="false" />

</system.web>
```

This part had been autogenerated upon the project creation several years ago.

If to create an ASP.NET MVC project for .NET Framework 4.7.2 now, then the Web.config will miss the above autogenerated part.

Do we still need this pages element and validateRequest="false" attribute?

Or in some point on the way from the WebPages to the MVC for .NET Framework 4.7.2 there were breaking changes that canceled the need of this setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MVC will prevent against potentially dangerous requests by default.**

To post any sort of script or HTML you need to add either:

1 - The *ValidateInput* attribute on a controller action method

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddEntry(MyModel model) {
    :
}
```

2 - The *AllowHtml* attribute on a model property

```
public class MyModel 
{
  [AllowHtml]
  public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
}
```

**The Pages Section of the Web Config is a WebForms thing**

"*Directives [in the pages element] specify settings used by the page and user-control compilers when they process ASP.NET Web Forms page (.aspx) and user control (.ascx) files.*" see ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.pagessection?view=netframework-4.8#remarks))

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

Is a left over from WebForms and is no longer needed by an MVC application.

So because MVC does not use any of that it is now irrelevant. Unless of course your application contains a mix of MVC and Webforms logic.

**Bottom Line**

Ideally you should never set *validateRequest* to false when using WebForms, or use *AllowHtml* or *ValidateInput(false)* in an MVC app because all three open security vulnerabilities in your code.

So should you remove it? Yes. It should probably not have been there in the first place.

Comment: MVC prevented the dangerous requests on the date the comment was auto-generated. Although it was required in the Web.config on purpose. What had happened by now? Have they changed the pages generation or pages element is required for WebForms only and nowadays we do not use them with MVC?

Comment: Updated explanation.